# Social buttons dont show on local computer

Tags: twitter, google-plus-one

I have recently been trying to add facebook like button , twitter button and google plus button.While I have managed to add the facebook like button on my site the twitter button and google+ button dont seem to apear.

I should mention that i am trying to add these on a local computer and while checking with jsFiddle they worked perfectly how can I make them work on my local computer

This is my twitter button:

```
<a href="https://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button" data-url="http://www.facebook.com/pages/WillKode/228217780608588" data-text="willkode" data-via="willkodeforyou">Tweet</a>
<script>
    !function(d,s,id){
        var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
        if(!d.getElementById(id)){
            js=d.createElement(s);
            js.id=id;js.src="//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";
            fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}
            (document,"script","twitter-wjs");
</script>
```

For the twitter button I am getting only the link without the twitter design

And this is my google+ button:

```
<!-- Place this tag where you want the +1 button to render -->
<g:plusone size="medium" annotation="inline"></g:plusone>

<!-- Place this render call where appropriate -->
<script type="text/javascript">
  (function() {
    var po = document.createElement('script'); po.type = 'text/javascript'; po.async = true;
    po.src = 'https://apis.google.com/js/plusone.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(po, s);
  })();
</script>
```

The google + 1 button dosent show at all  and also I dident find anywhere where I could add the link I wanted to share.On jsFiddle I get this when I add the code : });//]]>

Answer (score 0):

Check out @sourcecraft 's tweet on this discussion forum...https://dev.twitter.com/discussions/304?page=1

It seems that you have to run your site from a host...the buttons would not work otherwise....